# Angular - Passing FormBuilder values to Array results in empty string values

Tags: data-structures, angular-forms, angular2-formbuilder, angular-arrays

I have a form that I fill out using Angular's **FormBuilder**. This is the **FormBuilder** representation in the component typescript file:

```
constructor(private Form: FormBuilder) { }

AddStatusBoxForm = this.Form.group({
    cpuTempTopic: [''],
    uptimeTopic: [''],
    timeTopic: [''],
  });
```

I want to create a data structure that I can put these form values into, like so:

```
array: any[] = [this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('cpuTempTopic')?.value, 
                  this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('uptimeTopic')?.value, 
                  this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('timeTopic')?.value];
```

However console logging the array, results in empty strings. Yet if I console log the **FormBuilder** values on their own they print out fine:

```
console.log(this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('cpuTempTopic')?.value) // prints out fine
console.log(this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('uptimeTopic')?.value)
console.log(this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('timeTopic')?.value)
console.log(this.array) // prints out empty string
```

[image]

I can't figure out why this is the case, I can't seem to pass the **FormBuilder** values to any sort of data structure. I've also tried a **Map** and the same occurs where the passed in values seem to end up as empty strings in the data structure. Yet accessing the **FormBuilder** values on their own seems to work fine.

I've even tried to console log the type of the values from the **FormBuilder** which results in string:

```
console.log(typeof(this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('cpuTempTopic')?.value))
```

[image]

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because initially all the properties of the **FormBuilder** are initialized with empty string so while storing their values into an array will result with empty string values.
You need to **subscribe** to value changes of the **FormGroup** in order to update your array values in real time. You can refer the example below and bring modifications to your code accordingly.

```
addStatusBoxFormChangesSubscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit(): void {
this.addStatusBoxFormChangesSubscription = merge(
      this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('cpuTempTopic').valueChanges,
      this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('uptimeTopic').valueChanges,
      this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('timeTopic').valueChanges
    ).subscribe(() => (this.array = [this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('cpuTempTopic')?.value, 
                  this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('uptimeTopic')?.value, 
                  this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('timeTopic')?.value];));
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.addStatusBoxFormChangesSubscription?.unsubscribe();
  }
```

It is always a good practice to unsubscribe from the subscription when not working on the same page anymore.
You can explore more about form group here [FormGroup documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup).